# Why do I need to cast HttpURLConnection in this Java example?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am reading the book Java Programming Interviews Exposed. They offer this code sample, which I do not understand:

```
@Test
public void makeBareHttpRequest() throws IOException {

  final URL url = new URL("http", "en.wikipedia.org", "/");

  final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 

  connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

  final InputStream responseInputStream = connection.getInputStream();

  final int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode(); 

  final String response = IOUtils.toString(responseInputStream); 

  responseInputStream.close(); 

  assertEquals(200, responseCode); 

  System.out.printf("Response received: [%s]%n", response); 

}
```

Is there some general rule about when a variable needs to be cast (on the right side)? Why is it that HttpURLConnection is cast on the right side here:

```
  final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

but responseInputStream does not need to be cast on the right side here:

```
  final InputStream responseInputStream = connection.getInputStream();
```

How does a Java programmer know when to do this kind of casting, and when not to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this program, you cast into `HttpURLConnection` because you need to use a method that is available in `HttpURLConnection`, and not available in its parent classes, the method `setRequestMethod()`.

You *can* do this because you know that your URL is an HTTP URL, and therefore the `URLConnection` object that will be returned from it is going to be an `HttpURLConnection`.

You do not cast the result of `connection.getInputStream()` because it returns `InputStream` and you don't need any methods that are not defined in `InputStream`.

In general, you use the class that gives you the operations that you need - if you know that the result that you are getting is allowed to be cast to that class.

Answer (score 1):

A `URL` could be any type of scheme e.g. ftp, http, https, file etc.

So if you intend to do a HTTP operation you have to cast it to `HttpURLConnection`

See the next line, the request method is being set: `connection.setRequestMethod("GET");` This is specific to http requests

You don't need to cast `responseInputStream` because `IOUtils` is able to work with an instance of `InputStream` abstract class.